# Why can width 40% = 100%

Tags: html, css, github

I'm encountering an issue with the layout of my website when deployed on GitHub. Locally, everything works fine, but after uploading to GitHub, the layout appears broken.

I have a parent div set to a width of 100%, containing two child divs: child1 (width: 60%) and child2 (width: 40%). However, when deployed on GitHub, child2 seems to be taking up 100% of the width, and I can't see any sign of child1.

Here's a simplified version of my HTML and CSS structure:

**HTML:**

```css
.video-infor-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.ad_container {
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 6;
}

.ad_img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 20% 0 20%;
}

.infor_container {
  height: 450px;
  flex: 4;
}

.des_container {
  height: 294px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-infor-container">
  <div class="ad_container vid_infor_items">
    <img src="./asset/img/video/ver1.2/big.jpg" alt="" class="ad_img">
    <button class="play_button"><img src="./asset/img/video/p.webp" alt="" style="width: 80px;height:80px;" ></button>
  </div>

  <div class="infor_container vid_infor_items">
    <div class="des_container">
      <div class="des_title_conatiner">
        <p class="des_title">Version 1.2 Trailer</p>
        <img src="./asset/img/video/str.png" alt="" class="signature">;
      </div>
      <p>"That was a night in 1971, a night with pouring rain."
        <br>
        <br>"Heavily and hastily, sheets of rain formed a barrier, isolating the woods from the outside world."
        <br>
        <br>"Day after day, the smell of fungi and moist soil never disappeared. It lingered for one week, two weeks, three weeks ..."</p>
    </div>
```

Screenshots:

- [Local environment (working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K7Uh.jpg)
- [GitHub deployment (issue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEKdX.png)
- [Child2 taking 100% width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gECOc.png)

Steps I've tried to resolve the issue:

- Adjusting width properties for parent and child elements.
- Implementing **`float: left`** but without success.
- Changing the width of child1 to a fixed value (e.g., 1200px), but it remains invisible.

I've also inspected the elements using the browser's developer tools, but I can't seem to identify the cause of the issue.

Could anyone provide insights into why the child elements are not rendering correctly on GitHub, despite working fine locally? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Since you've called the missing div "ad_container", maybe it's falling foul of an ad-blocker?

Comment: FYI, your sample code is missing two closing `</div>`'s. When running it in Codepen.io, everything works. However when running this code within this SO-embedded snippet, there seems to be a dynamic CSS rule that's hiding the ad area for some reason. I can't tell how/why that is being generated. `.ad_container { display: none !important; }`. Whatever the case, it would be odd to use `float:` anywhere here; personally I would avoid that.